# Change default behavior of enter to tab in form submit on last input. jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, tabs, enter

I have a couple other questions like mine, but I couldn't understand their solutions. I've never used jQuery before. As I think this is probably a common question, I'm hoping someone can offer a clear solution aimed at beginners like myself that others can use as well.

In the code below I don't understand how code line below is supposed to work.

```
 $(this).nextAll('input:first').focus();
```

Here's the jQuery script:

```
    $('input').keydown(function(event) {

        if(event.which == 13) {
            if(!$(this).hasClass("last")){
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).nextAll('input:first').focus();
            }else {
                $("form").submit();   
            }
        }

    });
```

I've seen the above working in a different jsFiddle, just not with my form, and I'm not sure why.
[Link to my form at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfBNE/39/)

Answer (score 0):

The above jquery work with the code has only  and , remove the other codes like , then it work.